# What is a "logical successor"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I encountered one of instances of the phrase, and it appears to be some kind of idiom.

- [Douglas′ Proposals for a National Dividend: A Logical Successor to the Wage](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/03068299410049546)
- [Why Donald Trump Is Obama’s Logical Successor](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/why-donald-trump-is-obamas-logical-successor-and_us_5882a00ce4b0d96b98c1dc04)
- [Is the CFO a Logical Successor to the CEO?](https://www.bluesteps.com/blog/cfo-successor-ceo)

I can somewhat vaguely grasp the idea, but what does the phrase exactly mean? A *due successor*? A *de facto successor*? A *theoretical successor*? Or some other ways to understand?

Comment: I think *logical* means that they are applying some logical explanation to make their point. (Point A + Point B + Point C = the person should be the successor). I don't think there is a specific idiomatic explanation for the phrase.

Comment: *logical* = "something that follows because of logic"  So something like "the successor that makes the most sense".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that "logical" in those sentences would be equivalent to "foreseeable" (meaning, "expected according to the circumstances").

This is so much so that the string "logical foreseeable" can be found in quite a few good examples on the Internet, as if those two adjectives reinforced each other.